# Access Inline SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm reading an SVG from a string, and then display it using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. That works fine, but there's one thing I could not resolve:

The SVG contains some `<g>`, and I need to add click handlers to them which shall be handled by React.

Since the SVG is not constructed by React, I did not find a way to add click handlers to the groups.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you change the svg string? I mean can you append the `onClick=...` to the string that you use to form the svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the DOM elements using `findDOMNode` inside `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount () {
  const nodeList = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getElementsByTagName('g')
  // Do things with nodeList here, e.g. map over and attach click event
}
```